# How can a flow run multiple times without creating duplicates of user entries via HTTP?

Tags: power-automate, powerapps

I get Entra ID users via an HTTP GET method, which are then created via an HTTP Post method in Microsoft Saleshub.

Structure:

1. HTTP GET Entra ID User
2. JSON Analyzer

   ```
   {
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
       "value": {
           "type": "array",
           "items": {
               "type": "object",
               "properties": {
                   "surname": {
                       "type": "string"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. HTTP GET Saleshub User
4. JSON Analyzer

   ```
   {
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
       "value": {
           "type": "array",
           "items": {
               "type": "object",
               "properties": {
                   "lastname": {
                       "type": "string"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }
5. For each (value)
6. HTTP POST (Saleshub surname)

If I now execute the flow again, all the contacts created are recreated.

How can I configure the flow so that it only creates contacts that have not yet been created?

Comment: Without knowing more of your scenario, you would want to add an additional step between 3 & 4, to check if user exists already before submitting the POST (4).

Comment: Yes, thanks, but how?
I'm working atm only on lastname, which is surname in saleshub.
So how exactly can I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

- I GET all Entra ID User with a HTTP Request
- Analyze the json
- Call Saleshub
- create new string "true" = true
- create new string "array" = ""
- For each(body from entra id): array = false
- Check if lastname from Saleshub equals surname from entra id
- If array = true: create new lead, else do nothing